# Reaction mechanisms for organohalides from alcohols

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, halides

For the syntheses of organohalides from alcohols, what would plausible reaction mechanisms be for the three following reactions?

$$
\ce{R-OH + NaBr + H2SO4 -> R-Br + NaHSO4 + H2O}
$$

$$
\ce{R-OH + PCl5 -> R-Cl + POCl3 + HCl}
$$

$$
\ce{R-OH ->[red P][Br2 or I2] R-X}
$$

Comment: Explain what exactly? Also, could you give a reference of where you found them? They look wierd to me.

Comment: @MARamezani I found those reactions in organic chemistry textbook

Comment: Oh, you edited your question and removed the typo. That was what was giving me the creeps. Still, this remains unanswered: What should be explained?

Comment: @MARamezani Explain the mechanism involved in those reactions

Comment: I may be overreacting (and sorry for removing the tag) but I think this counts as homework. You should give some try or explain a little bit about the basics of finding reaction mechanisms.

Comment: @MARamezani this is not a homework question I posted this question to understand the reaction mechanisms involved in synthesis of ogranohalides from alcohol.

Comment: I think this *counts* as homework, not is literal homework. I'm letting it to play out. Hopefully it won't get closed. *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

Nucleophilic substitutions, regardless whether proceeding via $S_N1$ or $S_N2$ require a decent leaving group. $\ce{HO-}$, however, is a lousy leaving group!

To overcome this, several methods exist:

1. Perform the reaction under acidic conditions, where the alkanol is protonated. Your leaving group now is $\ce{H2O}$. In addition, the corresponding anion of sulfuric acid as a bad nucleophile.
2. React the alkanol with an acid chloride to form an ester and replace the ester group with a halide. Consider $\ce{PCl5}$ to be an acid chloride of phosphoric acid.
3. Form the acid halide *in situ* by reaction of phosphorous and iodine.